# How to fill in NA values with grouped means in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Say I have a df that looks like:

```
rat  let num
1     A   3 
3     c   12        
3     B   41        
1     B   NA        
1     A   NA    
2     B   2     
2     C   20        
1     C   NA    
2     A   33        
3     C   10
```

**I would like to group_by 'rat' and 'let' and get the mean of 'num' for each group and use that to fill in the NA values**.

I have done the grouping and got the mean but **don't know how to apply the values to fill in the NA values** in my original df. Different methods would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
df %>% group_by(rat,let) %>% summarise(num_avg = mean(num,na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Don't do this if you plan any further statistics.

Comment: I have just started learning R and this example is just a means to learn different methods of coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(rat,let) %>% mutate(num_avg = mean(num,na.rm=T))
df$num[is.na(df$num)] <- df$num_avg[is.na(df$num)]
```

Comment: If you want, filling NA using the group mean can be achieved with one line:  `df %>% 
  group_by(rat,let) %>% 
  mutate(num = ifelse(is.na(num), mean(num, na.rm = TRUE), num))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `ave` and `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df$num <- with(df, ave(num, rat, let, FUN = na.aggregate))
```